# How to strtok a string that saved in an array and save it into three different arrays in c?

Tags: c

I have a string stored in an array.

```
    char a1[20],a2[20],a3[20];
    Modem_Send("AT*PSHPLMN?\r\n",13);
    ModemWaitForAtResponse((char *)APN_Buffer,80,20);
    p = strtok (APN_Buffer,"'\":");
    while (p!= NULL)
    {
    printf ("%s\r\n",p);
    p = strtok (NULL, "\":");
    }
```

AT response will be for an ex:

```
"234","567","String"
```

I want to save `234, 567` and `String` in three different arrays.

I can able to parse the characters but stuck at saving them in different arrays.

The output of above code is

```
234
,
567
,
String
```

I need to save 234 in a1[20], 567 in a2[20], String in a3[20].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this CSV, or just a bunch of characters?

Comment: Just a characters

Comment: `sscanf("[\"343\",\"567\",\"String\"]","[\"%20[^"]s\",\"%20[^"]s\",\"%20[^"]s\"]",a1,a2,a3)`  assuming your arrays are 21 chars.

Comment: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Note to OP: "Write my code for me" style questions often get downvotes... Better to show what you have tried and what is the exact problem.

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
Will the AT response include the braces, double quotes and commas, or is that a representation of the three tokens returned by `strtok()`?  Which three arrays?  How are the arrays allocated?  How are you going to make sure that the data is copied from `APN_Buffer` to the three arrays?  Note that this information would be apparent if you provided a proper MCVE.

Comment: I've edited with more details. The data is copied from APN_Buffer. That's why I'm able to get the output of parsed array.

Comment: Your 2 calls to `strtok` have different sets of delimiters

Answer (score 0):

```
char a1[20], a2[20], a3[20];
char* arr[3] = {a1, a2, a3};
int i=0;
Modem_Send("AT*PSHPLMN?\r\n",13);
ModemWaitForAtResponse((char *)APN_Buffer,80,20);
p = strtok (APN_Buffer,"'\":");
while (p!= NULL)
{
 strcpy(arr[i++], p);
 printf ("%s\r\n",p);
 p = strtok (NULL, "\":");
}
```